# How to change default behaviour of "two-finger" click gesture?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, dom-events

How to rewrite the default behavior of when user presses on the touch-pad with two fingers. By default in Firefox and Chrome it shows menu, with default options.
In frontend code I'm using react, and want to detect multi-finger touch gesture with the following code :

```
const Page = () => {
  const onMouseDown = (e) => {
    if (e.buttons === 2) {
      // show custom menu
    }
  }
 
  return(
    <div onMouseDown={onMouseDown}>Click me</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, found an answer. Should have looked for it in a slightly different context. There was no need to connect two-finger gesture, and context menu. All that's required, to `preventDefault` on `onContextMenu` event.